# Problems with flashing motherboard Firmware using BlueNRG Gui

Tags: stm32, bluenrg

I use the Nucleo L476RG board with the X-Nucleo IDB05A1 expansion board from ST Microelectronics and want to test and communicate with it using the BlueNRG GUI.

But I have problems to connect with the GUI. I choose the right COM Port, open it and then it always says: 
"No device detected!" and "No firmware detected. Update firmware on the motherboard (Under tools menu)."
I tried to use that tool called "Flash Motherboard FW" and followed the steps and there it always says "No DFU Bootloader found"

Anyone has some advice to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build this example 
`C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\BlueNRG DK 1.7.1\Projects\Project\Virtual_COM_Port\` and upload it with conventional st-link utility.

Answer (score 0):

DK 1.7.1 is somewhat old.
Please use v2.02 if possible:
http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/evaluation-tool-software/stsw-bluenrg-dk.html

There are pre-built images in DK for MCU (Mother board).
Please try C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\BlueNRG DK 2.0.2\Firmware\STM32L1_prebuilt_images\BlueNRG_VCOM_1_8.hex

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BlrNRG-1 then reset the device before opening the comport.